# How do I use an IF-ELSE statement in a T-SQL join query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am a beginner using SQL Server. I would like to handle JOIN separately in different situations.

Desired processing example)

```
...

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    TABLE_AA ON A.ITEM1 = M.MAIN_ITEM

IF (A.ITEM = 0)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B B ON B.ITEM_NAME = A.ITEM_NAME
ELSE IF (A.ITEM == 1) L
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_C C ON C.ITEM_NAME = A.ITEM_NAME
```

I would like to perform another join to suit my situation.

It's too hard to know how to distinguish between queries.

Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_AA ON A.ITEM1 = M.MAIN_ITEM

LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B B ON B.ITEM_NAME = A.ITEM_NAME AND A.ITEM = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_C C ON C.ITEM_NAME = A.ITEM_NAME AND A.ITEM = 1
```